# How do I set keys on a global platform off-card repository?

Tags: c#, channel, javacard

I need a help with setting a secure channel between on-card and off-card parts of global platform. If I made myself unclear, hope an example will simplify the understanding of my problem.

Example:

If I use JCOP shell I need to type `set-key` command before `ext-auth`, like this:

> cm>  set-key 255/1/DES-ECB/404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
>   cm>  set-key 255/2/DES-ECB/404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
>   cm>  set-key 255/3/DES-ECB/404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f
>   cm>  init-update 255
>   cm>  ext-auth

Now I need to do the same thing (set-key) from c#. However, I couldn't find what is going on behind set-key command in JCOP shell, so I have no idea how to set-key from c#.

Answer (score 3):

The set-key command sets the key - or in your example the 3 parts of a 3DES key on client side. This command does not send an APDU to the card.

Afterwards Global Platform `INITIALIZE UPDATE` for establishing an Secure Channel is executed, which will be sent to the card in form as an APDU. In this step the important part is that a host-side generated challenge is sent to the card - and the card generated challenge is sent back from the card.

Afterwards the the `EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE` command is sent to the card.

See [GlobalPlatform Card Specification](http://www.win.tue.nl/pinpasjc/docs/Card%20Spec%20v2.1.1%20v0303.pdf) for details (concrete values for the APDU) of the `INITIALIZE UPDATE` and `EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE` commands. It also describes the two different protocols available for establishing an Secure Channel.

Comment: Hi, I know all that. However, what I dont know is how to set those keys from c#. One need access GlobalPlatform off-card part, but I have no idea how to do that... Can you help?
And btw, thank you for your answer :)

Comment: You should read for example the chapter "Secure Channel Protocol '02'" the the GP-Spec. It contains details about the cryptographic operations - and therefore where and how to use the key set with set-key command.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [globalplatform.net](https://github.com/sepulo/globalplatform.net), an open source implementation for Global Platform specification for .Net Framework. The following code snippet shows how to use it:

```
    SCardContext context = new SCardContext();
    context.Establish(SCardScope.System);
    string[] readers = context.GetReaders();
    IsoReader isoReader = new IsoReader(context, readers[3], SCardShareMode.Shared, SCardProtocol.Any, false);
    CommandApdu apdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case4Short, isoReader.ActiveProtocol)
    {
        CLA = 0x00,
        Instruction = InstructionCode.SelectFile,
        P1 = 0x04,
        P2 = 0x00,
        Data = new byte[] { 0xa0, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 }

    };

    Response response = isoReader.Transmit(apdu);

    GlobalPlatform gp = new GlobalPlatform();
    KeySet scKeys = new KeySet();
    scKeys.MacKey = new Key("404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f");
    scKeys.EncKey = new Key("404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f");
    scKeys.KekKey = new Key("404142434445464748494a4b4c4d4e4f");
    CommandAPDU initUpdate = gp.CreateInitUpdateCommand(scKeys,
        SecurityLevel.C_DECRYPTION | SecurityLevel.C_MAC, GlobalPlatform.SCP_ANY, GlobalPlatform.IMPL_OPTION_ANY);
    apdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case4Short, isoReader.ActiveProtocol)
    {
        CLA = (byte)initUpdate.CLA,
        INS = (byte)initUpdate.INS,
        P1 = (byte)initUpdate.P1,
        P2 = (byte)initUpdate.P2,
        Data = initUpdate.Data
    };
    response = isoReader.Transmit(apdu);
    if (response.SW1 == 0x6C)
    {
        apdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case2Short, isoReader.ActiveProtocol)
        {
            CLA = 0x00,
            Instruction = InstructionCode.GetResponse,
            P1 = 0x00,
            P2 = 0x00,
            Le = response.SW2

        };

        response = isoReader.Transmit(apdu);

    }

    byte[] responseData = response.GetData();

    gp.ProcessInitUpdateResponse(new ResponseAPDU(response.SW1, response.SW2, responseData));

    CommandAPDU extAuth = gp.CreateExternalAuthCommand();
    apdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case3Short, isoReader.ActiveProtocol)
    {
        CLA = (byte)extAuth.CLA,
        INS = (byte)extAuth.INS,
        P1 = (byte)extAuth.P1,
        P2 = (byte)extAuth.P2,
        Data = extAuth.Data
    };

    response = isoReader.Transmit(apdu);

    gp.ProcessExternalAuthResponse(new ResponseAPDU(response.SW1, response.SW2, response.GetData()));

    Key newMacKey = new Key("505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f", 0, 0);
    Key newEncKey = new Key("505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f", 1, 0);
    Key newKekKey = new Key("505152535455565758595a5b5c5d5e5f", 2, 0);

    List<Key> newKeys = new List<Key>();
    newKeys.Add(newMacKey);
    newKeys.Add(newEncKey);
    newKeys.Add(newKekKey);

    CommandAPDU putKey = gp.CreatePutKeyCommand(newKeys, true, false, GlobalPlatform.KEY_FORMAT_1);

    apdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case3Short, isoReader.ActiveProtocol)
    {
        CLA = (byte)putKey.CLA,
        INS = (byte)putKey.INS,
        P1 = (byte)putKey.P1,
        P2 = (byte)putKey.P2,
        Data = putKey.Data
    };

    response = isoReader.Transmit(apdu);
    if (response.SW1 == 0x6C)
    {
        apdu = new CommandApdu(IsoCase.Case2Short, isoReader.ActiveProtocol)
        {
            CLA = 0x00,
            Instruction = InstructionCode.GetResponse,
            P1 = 0x00,
            P2 = 0x00,
            Le = response.SW2

        };

        response = isoReader.Transmit(apdu);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The posted C# snippet by Bahribayli is the closer answer to the question. But I shall add here the explanation because my grandma is asking me about it and I like her to understand without involving any specification.

The `offcard` and the `card` needs to have an `a-priori` knowledge of the symmetric key values. The `offcard` and the `card` needs to have an `a-priori` agreement of the numerical index location of these keys. Now, there are two scenarios here. First scenario is that the `offcard` being the inquiring client, aggressively specify this key index number via the `p1` parameter of the `initialize update` apdu command, and the `card` will search for the keys inside corresponding to this index. Second scenario is that, a `p1` value of zero in the `initialize update` apdu command, means the `offcard` is  letting the `card` aggressively decide which index to use and then the `offcard` will look for the keys corresponding to this index. On both scenarios, the final result is that the `offcard` and the `card` now have agreed on an index value that hopefully point to the same keys in order to start securely talking. If the values of these keys differ, despite being on same index , then `initialize update` fails and no secure communication can continue.

The `set-key` command is a command that you execute on behalf of the `offcard` in anticipation of a key index existing and prepared on both sides that points to the same keys. Since only an index value is exchanged over an insecure channel, the `card` and the `offcard` still needs to determine if indeed that index number points to the same keys on both sides. From hereon, it is like a `*** boy meets girl ***` courtship affair wherein the boy will then starts to do weird cryptic talks to the girl in order to compute something and the girl does the same also. If the index did point to the same keys, this initial cryptic talks will verify and from here the second stage begins. Both sides creates `session keys` as the keys to use to continue talking.